# Will dual booting Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 on my low-end notebook affect performance

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, performance

I have been having some performance issues with Windows 7 on my Aspire E 15 Start (ES1-512-C4CT) since I am frequently using virtual machine for linux and my configuration doesnt't seem to be handling virtual machine + couple of pdfs + browser opened at the same time very well.

Because of that need I am thinking of dual booting windows and linux and am wondering if it will have some performance issues while in one of the two operating systems. (I am not sure if dual booting in general can cause performance issues on weaker computers)

If the issues are possible which linux distro would be the most forgiving for dual booting?

Comment: Having a dual boot configuration does not in and of itself affect performance. Only one of the operating systems is running at a time.  Not like running a VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your linux performance will be much better when running directly in your machine instead of virtualized.

Test a [live USB of 16.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (which is the latest long term support distribution) before installing to see how it will work. It will run slower from the USB, much faster once you install it.

Comment: And that linux installation will not affect my performance on windows when I decide to boot win7?

Comment: No performance change on windows. You will just have less available space on the hard drive. Be careful when partitioning and resizing. I've not done it in a while, but I remember you have to defrag the disk on Windows twice before foing it to ensure that there's no data at the end of the windows partition

Answer (score 0):

A system with core 2 duo of 2.6 GHz speed and 3gb of ram is enough for running Ubuntu in dual boot along with windows. Try with live Linux distro before installation.